# File Not Found Error Python

Tags: python, python-3.5, file-not-found

I'm trying to read a file on a specific path with `with open` method. Normally I do this with no problem, but right now there is a txt file on a specific path and Python raising `FileNotFoundError`. I formatted the pc today, I don't know the problem is about this or not.

I added Python to path. Version is 3.5. I tried these lines at the beginning of file;

```
#!/usr/bin/env
import os

#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
```

none of this worked. Still got the error. How can I fix this error? Searched questions about this problem but there are no answer for me.

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENTS**

Full traceback is:

```
`File "C:\Users\windows\Desktop\go.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open ("file") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file'`
```

I'm trying to open this file with these codes;

```
with open ("file") as f:
    t = f.readlines()
print (t)
```

The file is on the Desktop.

Comment: Did you pass the full path? Also make sure to use raw strings or something equivalent.

Comment: Well, you seem to think the desktop is the problem - so test that. Put the file in any other ('regular') path and run your code. Does it work? Then it is the desktop. Does it not? Then remove all references to "desktop" from your question ...

Comment: The shegang (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`) just decides which python to run. It has nothing to do with how an `open` in that program is going to work. You talk about opening a file but don't have an example that fails, which leaves us guessing what your problem is. It would be easier if you posted a small script that doesn't work and the stacktrack.

Comment: ...and tell us how you are running the script. Are you on the command line? What directory are you in?

Comment: Add `print(os.getcwd())` (after `import os`) so we can see where you are when you try to read the file. You seem to use a lot of names for your file, are you literally trying to open "file" when you want "file.txt"?

Comment: @GLHF, is  there an actual file called "file" when you `dir C:\Users\windows\Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. When you say "txt" file, do you mean the file has a ".txt" extension. If so, your code should include the extension.

```
with open ("file.txt") as f:
    t = f.readlines()
    print (t)
```

Comment: this is still part of the comment wars, its not justifiable as an answer yet.

Comment: @tdelaney. thanks for pointing it out. I had not checked the comments. will make sure to check next time..

Comment: Weirdly, when I add `txt` it worked. Normally I don't add extension, why it wants that now?

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
file = 'C:\Users\****\Desktop\1.txt'

with open (file) as f: # " inverted commas not required here
    t = f.readlines()
print (t)
```